# Why does introsort use heapsort rather than mergesort?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, sorting

As part of a homework assignment covering implementation of [introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) I'm asked why heapsort is used rather than mergesort (or other $O(n\log(n))$ algorithms for that matter).

> Introsort is a hybrid sorting algorithm that provides both fast average performance and (asymptotically) optimal worst-case performance. It begins with quicksort and switches to heapsort when the recursion depth exceeds a level based on (the logarithm of) the number of elements being sorted. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort), retrieved 2014-May-06.)

The only reason I can think of is that heapsort is "in place" ... But tbh I don't really understand why this would matter here though.

Comment: If introsort is part of the question, you'll have to tell us what it is before we can say anything.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: We are simply asked to make some pseudo code for intro sort and later on we are asked why it uses heapsort rather than mergesort.

Comment: @user672009 In that case, write down code for either and see what you find. The reason may or may not be related to performance.

Comment: I have concluded that since quicksort sorts in place we need to use another in place sorting algorithm. However I'm open for input.

Comment: While it's slightly outside of the scope of your question and the comments. it's worth mentioning that a well-known variant of introsort uses insertion sort rather than heapsort, since insertion sort is very fast when the dataset is sufficiently small.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 2 downsides of quicksort is that it requires $O(\log n)$ extra space (to keep the unsorted intervals) and bad pivot selection (or contrived sequences designed to make you select a bad pivot) may cause it to be a $O(n^2)$ time and $O(n)$ extra space algorithm.

Switching to heapsort when the recursion depth becomes too large (at around $\log n$) means we have a guaranteed upperbound that is $O(n \log n )$ time and $O( \log n)$ extra space.

Heapsort's $O(1)$ extra space requirement makes it a better choice to mergsort's $O(n)$ where for a contrived array that $n$ could still be large.

The reason heapsort isn't used for the full sort is because it is slower than quicksort (due in part to the hidden constants in the big O expression and in part to the cache behavior)

Comment: But heapsort is used... and I suspect it's because it's in place like quicksort.

Comment: I suspect that @user672009 is confused by your last sentence.  I'd suggest clarifying that introsort doesn't _start_ with heapsort because it is slower.

Comment: @user672009, $O(1)$ space _means_ "in place," and quicksort is _not quite_ in place because it requires $O(\lg n)$ extra space.

Comment: Additionally, heapsort has many more cache misses than introsort.

Comment: A good Quicksort implementation doesn't need O (n) space in the worst case, as long as it remembers the larger subinterval on the stack, and handles the smaller immediately.